# How to wait a return method until service response completes in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

I am calling a API service and assigning API response to any[] type.

Problem is method was execution was completed without waiting API response completes?

Below is my code

**Component.ts**

```
  this.catalogService.getCatalogsData().subscribe((data => {
     this._catalogData=data;
      console.log("catalogService function execution done!");
   }));
```

**service.ts**

```
public responseData:any=[];

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
      }
    public getCatalogsData(){

      debugger;

           this.http.get(this.APIUrl}}).toPromise().then(  
                data => {  
                      this.responseData = data as string [];  
                      console.log("API Response completed");
                  }  
              ); 

       return this.responseData;
      }

Logs Output: -
catalogService function execution done!
API Response completed

Expected OutPut:-
API Response completed
catalogService function execution done!
```

Comment: Please do some research on async generally and JS promises (or observables) specifically. There are so many questions, tutorials, articles and blog posts addressing this already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1- Your method is returning an array and you subscribed to it (although has async issue)

2- Method is returning array at the end and it happens before your promise result become ready

### Solution 1:

```
public getCatalogsData(): Promise<any>{

       return this.http.get(this.APIUrl).toPromise();
}

this.catalogService.getCatalogsData().then((data => {
     this._catalogData=data;
      console.log("catalogService function execution done!");
}));
```

### Solution 2

```
public getCatalogsData(): Observable<any>{
          return this.http.get(this.APIUrl);
}

this.catalogService.getCatalogsData().subscribe((data => {
     this._catalogData=data;
      console.log("catalogService function execution done!");
}));
```

### Note

In both solutions you don't need `public responseData:any=[];` in your service